# Why does chaining not work in IE8 / 9

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, dom, chaining

Why does this work:

```
el = document.getElementById('STR');
if( el ){
    el.checked = true;
    el2 = el.cloneNode(false);
    el.parentNode.insertBefore(el2, el);
    el2.setAttribute('id','');
    el2.setAttribute('disabled','disabled');
    el2.removeAttribute('name');
    el.removeAttribute("disabled");
    el.style.display="none";
}
```

but this not:

```
el = document.getElementById('STR');
if( el ){
    el.checked = true;
    el2 = el.cloneNode(false);
    el.parentNode.insertBefore(el2, el);
    el2.setAttribute('id','');
    el2.setAttribute('disabled','disabled').removeAttribute('name');
    el.removeAttribute("disabled");
    el.style.display="none";
}
```

In Firefox / Chrome the last snippet works perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That does not actually work in any browser I know of. The DOM "setAttribute()" function returns `undefined` in Firefox and Chrome (and, probably IE as well).

The "chaining" code style is something that you can do in JavaScript if you want, but it requires a framework of some sort to explicitly implement it. DOM methods generally do not work that way.